# Determining which controller and action is handling a particular URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Given a particular URL, how do I find out for sure which controller action it is being routed to (perhaps in the context of a large application with many controllers and a complex route registry)?

**I'm not asking how to configure routes**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this for controller:

```
string controller = RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
```

And for action:

```
string action = RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
```

For example you can use it in your base controller class:

```
    public class YouControllerBase: Controller
    {
          protected override void Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
          {
              string controller = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
              string action = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
          }
   }
```

Or use it in global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(
            new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
        var action = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
    }
```

Comment: Great thanks - this is simple and useful. The disadvantage is the assumption that every controller reliably inherits from a common base class.

Comment: I edited the post. You can use global.asax instead if you don't wish to create base controller class

Answer (score 9):

You could try this [ASP.NET Routing Debugger](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/):

[image]
<sub>(source: [haacked.com](http://haacked.com/images/haacked_com/WindowsLiveWriter/UrlRoutingDebugger_EEBA/route-debugger-screenshot.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

pete,

in code, you can use an actionfilter to determine whats going on:

```
public class AddUrlInfoToSessionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            // where we are now - do something with the vars in real app
            var currentActionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            var currentControllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            var currentRouteData = filterContext.RouteData;
            var currentUrlInfo = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
            string url = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(filterContext.RequestContext, currentRouteData.Values).VirtualPath;
        }
    }
}
```

and then decorate each controller that your interested in as below (or put it onto a basecontroller):

```
[HandleError]
[AddUrlInfoToSessionAttribute]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // controller stuff
}

[AddUrlInfoToSession]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{

}
```

hope this helps

jim

**EDIT:** just tidied the example up a bit by adding the following to the filter method:

string url = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(filterContext.RequestContext, currentRouteData.Values).VirtualPath;

Comment: I'm interested in all the controllers.

Comment: pete - you'd then have to decorate all the controllers with the [AddUrlInfoToSessionAttribute] flag. this may or not be a big issue depending on the existing codebase. i actually use a more fully featured version of the above code in a few apps in order to keep track of previous route data, so it does work well.

Comment: I think in most cases an app would have a generally-used base class, so if that could be relied on then this idea should work... I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

Two simple steps:

1. Add 2 reference in your project: `MvcFakes.dll,RouteDebugger.dll`
2. Entering the following URL:      `/RouteDebugger`

The 2 dlls are contained [here](http://stephenwalther.com/downloads/AspNetMvcUnleashed/Chapter09/Chapter09Code.zip)

Chapter09Code.zip\Code\CS\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\bin

Answer (score 0):

The Controller and Action that are used are determined by the registered routes. Look in your Global.ascx.cs

Here is the default route mapping that comes as standard with a new MVC app. So if your url is http://yourdomain/SomeSiteSection/SomeThing/ then MVC will look for a controller called SomeSiteSectionController and an Action called SomeThing.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    //...

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Routes that are registered to resolve the URL

The default conventions is as follows :

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

Index action will be called on HomeController.